# using cPickle returns only the first entry in the file

Tags: python, pickle, eoferror

I am storing a dictionary object into file using cPickle, and not able to get any other entry other than the first one. Initially the file `tweets.pkl` is empty, and the `EOFError` is raised. I am sure it has something to do with it. Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                        

from urllib import urlencode, urlopen
from simplejson import loads
from hashlib import md5
from collections import defaultdict
import json
import cPickle as pickle

def fetch_tweets(new_feeds):
    dic = json.loads(new_feeds)
    feeds_file = open('tweets.pkl','r+b')
    try:
        feeds = pickle.load(feeds_file)
    except EOFError:
    #THIS IS BAD
        feeds = defaultdict()
    feeds_file.close()
    # RETURNS ONLY THE FIRST FEED ENTRY                                            
    for i in feeds.iteritems():
        print str(i)

    for i in dic['results']:
        hash = computeHash(i['text'])

        if hash not in feeds:
            appendfeed(hash, i, 'tweets.pkl')


def appendfeed(hash, new_feed, file):
    feed = defaultdict()
    file = open(file, 'a+b')
    feed[hash] = new_feed
    pickle.dump(feed, file)
    file.close()

def computeHash(data):
    h = md5(data.encode('utf-8'))
    return h.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're constructing a new dictionary (`feed = defaultdict()`) every time `appendfeed` is called, so that new dictionary loses all previous references. You're then appending the new (single-entry) dict to the file.

If you want to restore multiple separate calls to `dump` like this, then you will need multiple matching calls to `load` or `unpickle`, I believe. Each call should then return a separate `dict` with one element each.

If you want to store one dictionary with multiple keys, lose the `append` mode and just re-pickle the entire dictionary whenever you need to save. If you want something more efficient for storing simple mappings, have a look at [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) or [shove](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/shove)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about shelve. It is a more efficient way.

Comment: Glad to help. Regards from just south of Mountain View :)